# Moving .png files with mv and wildcards error

Tags: terminal, debian, wildcard, mv, linux-mint

I've got a folder full of thousands of pictures. I want to move all of the .png files back one directory.. I tried

```
 mv -i *.png ../
```

But get the following error:

```
mv: invalid option -- 'p'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order to prevent `mv` from trying to interpret a file with a leading dash (e.g. `-pbla.png`) as an option (like `-p bla.png`), you can separate the flags from the files using a double dash `--`:

```
mv -i -- *.png ../
```

another simple way is to prefix the current path `./` to each filename:

```
mv -i ./*.png ../
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mv *.png ../
```

This works on every linux distribution.